# Confusion with Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Show that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists integers $m,n$ such that $$0 < |mx - n| < \epsilon$$

So, I was trying to think of how to do this and thought dividing through the inequality by $n$ would be useful, but I didn't really know where to go from there. That is, $$0<|\frac{m}{n}x - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{n}$$

Does anyone know how to solve this question?

Comment: Take $x$ positive. Look at the fractional part of $ix$, where $i$ ranges over the positive integers. The fractional parts are all different. By Pigeonhole Principle, there are $i\lt j$ such that the fractional part of $xi$ is close to the fractional part of $xj$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ehh...

Comment: If you have trouble building a solution, I can do it (tomorrow, getting late here).